# WebdriverIO - Collect drop down elements into an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, webdriver-io

I have a drop down in my application that looks similar to this -

```
<select>
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">Saab</option>
  <option value="3">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

How would I collect the car brand options into an array?  I know the java selenium bindings have the select class to help with this however there doesn't appear to be an equivalent solution using webdriverio?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium get all options from drop down in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39566382/selenium-get-all-options-from-drop-down-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use .elements method based on tag  for the option tag this should return you JSON Objects.
Here is the link that states that:
http://webdriver.io/guide/usage/selectors.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to find all the `<option>` elements in the select list, and then convert the list of elements to a flat list of values using the `.map()` method:

```
browser.getElements('option').map(option => option.getText());
```